# set user details in state after successful api call - Redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a "My Profile" form that displays the details of the user.

Api call to fetch user data is as follows.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserDetails();
  }
```

Saga file is as follows

```
function* fetchUserDetails() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(userDetailsApi);
    const user = response.data.user;

    // dispatch a success action to the store
    yield put({ type: types.USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, user});

  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch a failure action to the store with the error
    yield put({ type: types.USER_DETAILS_FAILURE, error });
  }
}

export function* watchUserFetchRequest() {
  yield takeLatest(types.USER_DETAILS_REQUEST, fetchUserDetails);
}
```

Reducer is as follows

```
export default function reducer(state = {}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Now i need to set the user details in state** so that when the form values are changed, i can call the handleChange function to update the state.

If i had used redux thunk, i could have used something like as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserDetails().then(() => {
      this.setState({ user });
    });

}
```

so that the user state contains all details of user and if a user property changes then the state can be updated using handleChange method .

That is, 
After the api call, i need is something like

```
state  = {
   email: user@company.com,
   name: 'Ken'
}
```

How to achieve the same using redux saga?

Comment: can't you just add `SET_USER` or `UPDATE_USER` in reducer to set any user changes? and every form change will dispatch a `SET_USER` or `UPDATE_USER` action?

Comment: You can use mapStateToProps to get the data from the redux store in your component and set it in a component's state.

Comment: What you need is derived state. Check the docs for getDerivedStateFromProps. However, I suggest you to stop and rethink the approach. If you need redux, then rely on redux fully to manage that component's state. If you try to mix local state and props, things are going to get unnecessarily complex and hard to maintain.